# how to have continuous integration builds for windows phone 7 applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, build, continuous-integration

I want to have continuous integration  and nightly builds for my windows phone 7 application.
any help to kick start this.

Comment: What kind of features do you expect? Unittest, coverage, ...

Comment: @Erno yes Unit tests , over night builds etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally tried to set this up, but some colleagues with more experience suggests, that unit testing is handled by including the same files in two projects, where one of them is a regular WP7 project (where nunit is non-existant and MStests are hard to control) and the other project is a regular library. That way the unit tests can run in the library project which tests the same files as the WP7 project uses to build the xap file. The obvious problem is of course, that the actual linking in the two projects are different, but for CI purposes it seems excusable.